# Scheduling SQS messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, scheduled-tasks, amazon-sqs

My use case is as follows: I need to be able to schedule SQS messages in such a way that scheduled messages can be added to a queue on a specific date/time, and also on a recurring basis as needed.

At the implementation level, what I'm basically be looking to do is have some function I can call where I pass in the SQS queue, message, and schedule I want it to run on, without having to build the actual scheduler logic.

I haven't seen anything in AWS itself that seems to allow for that, I also didn't get the impression Lambda functions would do exactly what I need unless I'm missing something.

Is there any other third party cloud service for scheduled processes I should look into, or am I better off in the end just running a scheduling machine at AWS and have some REST API that can add cron jobs/windows scheduled tasks to it that will handle the scheduling of SQS messages?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I could see two slightly different ways of accomplishing this, both based on Cloudwatch [scheduled events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html).  The first would be to have Cloudwatch fire off a Lambda.  The Lambda would either have the needed parameters or would get them from somewhere else - for example, a DynamoDB table.  Otherwise, the rule target allows you to specify a SQS queue - skipping the Lambda.  But I'm not sure if that would have the configuration ability you'd want.

Either way, checkout Cloudwatch -> Events -> Create Rule in the AWS console to see your choices.

Answer (score 2):

It's now 2023, I use AWS EventBridge > Rules, you can add scheduled rules similar to cron for pushing messages onto the SQS queue.

https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/events/home?region=us-west-2#/rules

Answer (score 0):

This is a completely selfish answer but I helped create a service for this need which may come in handy for others not on AWS or only adopting some AWS features called [anticipated.io](https://anticipated.io) which allows you to do just that - schedule SQS.  You can also schedule web hooks.